# React app keeps refreshing when changing i18next language in combination with authenticated routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have a react-app with authentication (cookie based) with a login route and a profile route. The profile route is fetching the profile data and puts the data in a form. One of the fields is a language field. I'm using the `useEffect` hook to watch the language property and use `i18n.changeLanguage()` to change the language.

For some reason the page keeps refreshing when I add this code. It must be a combination of this code together with the code I'm using the check if the user is authenticated to access the route. When I comment out the protectedRoute function or the useEffect hook it's working but I obviously need both.

A small breakdown of the protectedRoute function and authContext.

The routes are wrapped in an AuthProvider

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <AuthProvider>
                <Router />
            </AuthProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
```

Inside the AuthProvider I have a `user` and `isAuthenticated` state. Both starting with a value of `null`. On mount a call with or without a cookie is done to the backend to get the user info. If a user object is returned with an id the `isAuthenticated` state is set to true.

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfo();
  }, []);

  const getUserInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await authService.me();

      setIsAuthenticated(true);
      setUser(data);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
      setUser({});
    }
  };

  const setAuthInfo = (user) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(!!(user && user.id));
    setUser(user);
  };

...
```

As long as isAuthenticated is `null` a loading state is rendered instead of a route.

```
  if (authContext.isAuthenticated === null) {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Loading...</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
    return authContext.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Outlet />
    ) : (
      <Navigate to="/login" replace />
    );
  };

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

      <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/profile" replace />} />
        <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfileOverview />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
```

The profile page can be accessed when the `isAuthenticated` state is true. Inside the profile page the user profile information is fetched and with a reset set into the form state. This will trigger the useEffect hook watching the `formData.language` property which will set the language to the user's language. This leads to a continuous refresh and I can't find the reason why or what I'm doing wrong.

```
const Profile = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  const { formData, reset, handleSubmit, handleChange } = useForm({});

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Get profile data");
    getProfileInfo();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(formData.language);
  }, [formData.language]);

  const getProfileInfo = async () => {
    const { data } = await profileService.getProfileInfo();
    reset(data);
  };

  const submit = (values) => {
    console.log("submit");
  };

...
```

[Codesandbox demo over here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-feather-ncd0q9?file=/src/pages/Profile.js). I have put a console.log inside the useEffect on the profile page so you can see that it keeps refreshing. Login can be done without credentials. All fetches are done with a setTimeout to fake real calls.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-feather-ncd0q9?file=/src/pages/Profile.js) and modified within `Profile.js`. The idea is to block additional requests to `i18n.changeLanguage` until the previous request has finished *and* the language was truly updated.

```
  // Use a state variable to verify we aren't already loading
  const [isLoadingLanguage, setLoadingLanguage] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Verify we aren't loading and are actually changing the language
    if (!isLoadingLanguage && formData.language !== language) {
      const load = async () => {
        // Set the state as loading so we don't perform additional requests
        setLoadingLanguage(true);

        // Since this method returns a promise, and useEffect does not allow async/await easily,
        // make and call an async method so we can await changeLanguage
        await i18n.changeLanguage(formData.language);

        // Originally, we wanted to set this again to update when the formData language updated, but we'll do in submit
        // setLoadingLanguage(false);
      };
      load();
    }
  }, [i18n, formData.language]);
```

I would note, getting this to work in the sandbox required removing the line to `i18n.changeLanguage` so perpetual renders would not keep submitting requests. Then, adding back the `useEffect` above loaded the form and provided single submissions.

**Edit:** To prevent `i18n.changeLanguage` from rendering the component again we can do a few things.

- Remove the `setLoadingLanguage(false)` from the `useEffect` so we don't trigger a language change until we submit
- Add `i18n.changeLanguage` to the `submit` method AND `localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(formData)` to retain the state when we do submit

```
  const submit = (values) => {
    localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(formData));
    i18n.changeLanguage(formData.language);
    console.log("submit");
  };
```

- Retrieve any localStorage item for "formData" in place of the `getProfileInfo`

```
export default {
  getProfileInfo() {
    console.log({ localStorage });
    const profileData =
      localStorage.getItem("formData") !== null
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("formData"))
        : {
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Doe",
            language: "nl"
          };

    const response = {
      data: profileData
    };

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(response), 100);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: In if `(!isLoadingLanguage && formData.language !== language)` where does the language variable come from?

Comment: The `language` object that `formData.language` compares against comes from the `useTranslation` hook.

Comment: I changed the demo with your suggestion (same link) but now the language is resetting after changing the language property

Comment: Looks like `changeLanguage` reloads the page to update the language per the translations. Setting the `formData` in `localStorage` will persist the form through the page reload. You can then set `formData` if `localStorage` had anything to persist, otherwise default to the `getProfileInfo` response.

If the intent is to only call `changeLanguage` when the submit button is clicked, the `useEffect` updating language will need modification, too.

Comment: I don't know if it is common behaviour that the page reloads after changeLanguage is done. Can't find any information about this in the documentation.

Comment: In the [i18next github](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/blob/e401175e1912a837e883923121e997df81ba4111/src/i18next.js), the `I18n` class extends `EventEmitter` and implements `changeLanguage` which emits a `lanagaugeChanged` event. In order to update what's on the screen to the new language, a reload will occur, arguably from the `languageChanged` event emitted.